# Unable to load css and bootstrap between two folders

Tags: html, css, jsp, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to load a html file from TaskCreation folder in to the Checking.jsp file in jsp folder. Initially html is loading fine but including in jsp file bootstrap and css are not loading. Help me out with this.

[For path image click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDHGG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use linkrel attribute to access external stylesheets

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
```

if you want to go back one folder ie. if your folder path is one step down the current. then use.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/custom.css">
```